# Passwords for a site with puzzle progression

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, passwords, .htpasswd

I am trying to program my first web-based puzzle game, where the answer to puzzle-one is the key to get to puzzle-2, and so on.  I am stuck on how to set "answers" to puzzles that serve as passwords for the next page.

I have thus far considered a javascript code, but nixed it because anyone can see the password via developers' window.  .htaccess file was the other viable option, which I am trying with limited success.

Are there other methods to set an answer key to access "page 2" from "page 1", where input area & submit button are embedded within page 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bcrypt to generate a hash from the correct password:

```
const saltRounds = 10;
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(correctAnswer, saltRounds);
```

Then you can check for the answer given by the user:

```
const resp = bcrypt.compareSync(answer, hash);
```

If the the answer is the same as the correctAnswer then the function returns true.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't really understand the implementation fully (I am very new at this) but know I need to learn bcrypt basics.